# Как поместить картинку в Button в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как поместить картинку в Button в WPF?
Попробовал сделать так, но картинка не отображается:

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="test.png"></Image>
</Button>
```

Comment: [Кнопки с иконкой WPF](https://habrahabr.ru/post/157337/) - может поможет)

Answer (score 3):

Также можно объявить картинку в качестве ресурса внутри `XAML`:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <Image x:Key="resourceImage" Source="..."/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Ну а затем использовать данный ресурс в своей кнопке так:

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource resourceImage}" />
```

Но, Важно помнить о том, что картинка должна быть ресурсом. Для этого щелкаем правой кнопкой мыши на изображении выбираем <kbd>Properties</kbd> находим там <kbd>BuildAction</kbd> и помечаем ее как ресурс <kbd>Resource</kbd>. Иначе картинка попросту затеряется.

Ссылка на источник: [Add an Image in a WPF button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17515867/5275890)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="Images/paral.png" Height="23" Width="23"/>
</Button>
```

Правой по картинке -> Свойства -> Действия при сборке ->Resource

Comment: Спасибо большое!